# Correct client-server framework architecture approach (different server versions)

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, frameworks

I am trying to design and implement a framework to communicate with server (it's an iOS framework written in Swift). The challenge I am facing is the architecture - there are two ways of communicating with the server and I have to implement both (different versions). I really want to achieve having a stateless client, with methods such as: `Client.authenticate()` or `Client.downloadFile()`. The problem is when having two implementations I would end up with methods in my Client class like this one:

```
public class func authenticate(state: state) {
    if (state.type == 1) {
        Client1.authenticate(state)
    } else {
        Client2.authenticate(state)
    }
}
```

Repeated for every single method...

I wanted to initially keep the client like this - stateless and static and have only state objects that hold the actual state as there could be many connections to the server with various states. By that I wanted to avoid having the client as an object and both holding the state and performing the calls to the server. The problem is that this approach is just...dirty I guess. What would be a more DRY, readable and sustainable way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your intention without more code samples, but the patterns I will present to you will surely clear things up for you.

If your Client class always uses either `Client1` or `Client2` (or more specifically, if your every client object `state` variable doesn't change through it's instances lifetime) you should use **Dependency Injection**.

You create a `procol` (Let's call it `RemoteClient` with `authenticate` method (and every other method that the server client should implement) and make `Client1` and `Client2` conform to that protocol.

Now you make your Client class to accept a `RemoteClient` in it's constructor.

Now whatever creates the Client object, it can decide what to **inject** into the constructor: the `Client1` concrete class object, or `Client2`.

There's a lot of articles about `Dependency Injection` so I won't cover it in much detail.

[Example article](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/dependency-injection-ios/)

You can also use the **Strategy design pattern**, which is very similiar but kind of different in intent:

[Strategy design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy)

[Difference between DI and Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176520/what-is-the-difference-between-strategy-pattern-and-dependency-injection)

**EDIT**

After you've clarified what you want to do in comments below:

In that case, you can use reflection/metadata and use dictionary/map to invoke the client you want.

(pseudocode)

```
enum ServerType 
{ 
   client1,
   client2
}

 Dictionary* serversDictionary; // key = ServerType , value = object of protocol type RemoteLocation

static init
 {
    serversDictionary[client1] = Client1.self; // using swift class metadata
    serversDictionary[client2] = Client2.self; // using swift class metadata  
  }

static authenticate(ServerType type) {

 let locationToSendAuthTo = serversDictionary[type]; 
 locationToSendAuthTo.authenticate(type);
}
```

I'm not sure if Swift works that way because I've just started using it. I'm not sure if you can call a static method on a class type. The docs are pretty thin on that.

More here:
[Swift class introspection & generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049673/swift-class-introspection-generics)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I gave up on my first initial idea and actually did what you suggested.I can see I failed to clarify the core thing I wanted to achieve - Client being a static class(not an initialized object).Just like I would call POST in Alamofire(without initializing the client) I wanted to call methods on the static client(injecting the state everytime).The challenge was how to do this when I need two implementations of the client - I would have to have a 'router' in order to call `Client.performSth()` without the "user" of the SDK having to specify which one(Client1 or Client2).

Comment: Then the way how to determine which client to use would be through the state object. But that would generate the kind of method I posted in my question - for every method I would want to expose - same thing with switch, calling the correct implementation...